# Repeated JOptionPane pop-up?

Tags: java, if-statement

so I'm writing a program that gives the number of minutes for every input of x seconds... now the issue is that once I type in the first value, it asks for another value and divides that....and another value...and another...and so on... how can I get it to only give me one value and finish with that one value instead of a never-ending thing?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class TimeCalculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {

double seconds;
String input;

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any number of seconds");

seconds = Double.parseDouble(input);

if (seconds >= 60);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "There are " + (seconds/60) + " minutes in " + seconds + " seconds.");


if (seconds >= 3600);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "There are " + (seconds/60) + " minutes in " + seconds + " seconds.");

if (seconds >= 86400);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "There are " + (seconds/60) + " minutes in " + seconds + " seconds.");

System.exit(0);




}
}
```

Comment: "`if (seconds >= 60);`" Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` for message. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - remove the semicolons after each `if` statement. Secondly, change the `showInputDialog` to `showMessageDialog` when you are not asking for input. Thirdly, correct the logic of your code:

```
class TimeCalculator{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double seconds;
        String input;

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any number of seconds");

        seconds = Double.parseDouble(input);

        if (seconds >= 60)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + (seconds / 60) + " minutes in " + seconds + " seconds.");

        if (seconds >= 3600)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + (seconds / 3600) + " hours in " + seconds + " seconds.");

        if (seconds >= 86400)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "There are " + (seconds / 86400) + " days in " + seconds + " seconds.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the semicolons and it didn't change anything

Comment: @Daoud I have edited my answer. Please accept it as the correct answer if it helps.

Comment: So I did this and when I ran it, 4 errors came up that said "Cannot find symbol" and pointed toward the J in JOptionPane

Comment: @Daoud just add "import javax.swing.JOptionPane;" at the begining of the code.

Comment: Sweet thanks! Now there is just one final issue...it gives me hours AND minutes... but i only want minutes? I see you changed the dialog to hours in and days in...but i only want the # of minutes for any input. I changed it back to minutes in for everything, but it gives me two solutions for the input. So basically says there are x minutes in x seconds, twice

Comment: I have changed the division for everything to seconds/60 because that is what is needed to get minutes out of everything. Now when I put in something like 90,000 it gives me 3 resolution panes telling me the exact same thing.... what do i  need to do to get one pane for each solution? I know it does 3 because of how my statements are made...idk what to do

Comment: @Daoud I do not really know what this program should do. Do you want to count only minutes? Why do you have 3 if statements? Do you want it to read from user only once?

Comment: You know what... my professor changed the assignment and didn't do it properly so I got confused and still had one part of the earlier assignment in .... i just made it one IF statement instead. Thanks for the help :)